# Why selenium(python) can't find button?

Tags: python, selenium

When I enter my account and make request to the invite link and turns out that invite link expired, selenium correctly determines the button "Continue to Discord":

`button = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("[type='button']")`

But when invite is still valid, selenium can't determine button "Accept Invite". Codes of these both buttons:

`<button type="button" class="marginTop40-i-78cZ button-3k0cO7 button-38aScr lookFilled-1Gx00P colorBrand-3pXr91 sizeLarge-1vSeWK fullWidth-1orjjo grow-q77ONN"><div class="contents-18-Yxp">Accept Invite</div></button>`

`<button type="button" class="marginTop40-i-78cZ button-3k0cO7 button-38aScr lookFilled-1Gx00P colorBrand-3pXr91 sizeLarge-1vSeWK fullWidth-1orjjo grow-q77ONN"><div class="contents-18-Yxp">Continue to Discord</div></button>`

Why can't selenium find first button if their codes are actually the same? I tried almost all methods. By xpath, by css selector and by class. Nothing helped. Seems like changing browser doesn't help too. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried to put a wait. Maybe the button is not present when that line of code is executed

Comment: Please mention the error or exceptions you are getting in the console

Comment: @RoshanKumar ```Message: Unable to locate element:``` No such element exception.

Comment: @FranciscoPuga I already wait for page loaded: ```WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(lambda driver: driver.execute_script('return document.readyState') == 'complete')```

Comment: Is the button is on the new window or in the pop-up menu? Because you might be getting this exception 'cause of this. Also, make sure the element is not in the iframe If possible attach the screenshot of the page/element you are trying to access.

Comment: @RoshanKumar the same window:
https://skr.sh/s8WGTXhfVX1

Comment: And if link is expired: https://skr.sh/s8Wu7enTsVA